# Custom shortcode works in Elementor editor but not on frontend

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, child-theme

I'm used to creating custom shortcodes through my child theme and Elementor, never a problem.

However this time something is wrong, when I inserted the shortcode widget in Elementor editor my code is correctly showing, but after saving I visit the page, its blank, like the shortcode was never processed.

Anyone have any idea of why this is happening?

This is the code where i create the shortcode:

```
    <?php 
    add_shortcode('test', function () {
    ob_start();
    require_once (locate_template('views/test.php'));
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```

Inside the file views/test.php a simple form, nothing crazy.

This is the screen of Elementor editor where the shortcode is showing:

[image]

[image]

If i visit the page it's completely blank.

Comment: Could you provide more details, the code you used, maybe some screenshots as to what happens.

Comment: there is no shortcode to debug in your question. Note that Elementor and other 3rd party dev support is off topic on this stack

Comment: @Tom I updated the post, i didn't know about the 3rd party thing.

Comment: is it just the shortcode missing on the page, or is it everything? If it's everything it sounds like the classic white screen of death, check your PHP error log

Comment: Can you post the code that you have in `views/test.php`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `require_once`, you are passing a relative path and that path doesn't exist.

Assuming the `test.php` file you want to require is in this path

`wp-content/themes/your-theme/views/test.php`

You can use the following

```php
require_once locate_template('views/test.php');
```

Consider using `include` instead of `require_one`, if this shortcode is not 100% necessary for your site to function, its best to use include as this way you will not receive a fatal error because that file doesn't exist.

Comment: @Sorius_45 Could you update your question with the new code?

Comment: Updated, i see your point but i don't get why the shortcode is showing just fine in Elementor editor.

Comment: Should work, all testing that i have done on my local env worked as expected. I assume the path is somehow incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the solution. Thanks for all the answers.

This is the code now:

```
add_shortcode('test', function () {
    ob_start();
    include('views/test.php');
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```

Now it shows up on frontend, i don't know why with `require_once` was not working, but if i use `include` it works fine.